# Hibernate map declared in abstract class not inherited in subclasses

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an abstract class A and two classes B and C implementing A.

```
abstract class A implements Serializable {
  Long id
  String code
  String description
  Map<Locale, String> localizedDescriptions 
}

class B implements A {}

class C implements A {}
```

With the following hibernate mapping:

```
<class name="A" abstract="true">

    <id name="id">
        <generator class="org.hibernate.id.enhanced.TableGenerator"/>
    </id>

    <property name="code" unique="true" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="description" not-null="true"/>

    <map name="localizedDescriptions" lazy="false">
        <key property-ref="code" column="code"/>
        <index column="locale" type="locale"/>
        <element column="description" type="string" not-null="true"/>
    </map>

    <union-subclass name="B"/>
    <union-subclass name="C"/>
```

The B and C database tables I get have the fields id, code and description as expected. However there are no b_localized_descriptions or c_localized_descriptions tables but there's a a_localized_descriptions table, which isn't what I want.
So, is it possible to have the desired behaviour without having to define the map for every subclass ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<union-subclass name=”C”>
<property name=”salary” column=”SALARY” />
<property name=”bonus” column=”BONUS” />
</union-subclass>
```

Specify the properties within the union subclass xml tag that you would like included.

Comment: Well, in my question I said "without having to define the map [and the common properties] for every subclass"